# Ion item doesn't drag with ion-input

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop, ionic4

When I use `ion-input` inside `ion-item` it doesn't allow to drag using `ion-icon`. But if I use ion-label it allows to drag using icon.

Following doesn't allow to drag.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input placeholder="Name"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon slot="end" name="move" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
```

Following  allows to drag.

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label>You can drag me.</ion-label>
   <ion-icon slot="end" name="move" draggable="true" style="cursor: move;"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: If what you want to do is reorder the items, the recent solution is explained here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder

Comment: I want to do drag and drop in grid with multiple row and columns.